# Documentation when not using getters and setters

Tags: java, php, python, setter, getter

In Java I use getters/setters when I have simple models/pojos. I find that the code becomes self-documenting when you do it this way. Calling getName() will return a name, I don't need to care how it's mapped to some database and so on.

Problems rise when using languages where getters and setters start feeling clunky, like in Python, and I often hear people saying that they are bad. For example some time a go I had a PHP project in which some of the data was just queried from the database and column values mapped to the objects/dictionaries. What I found out was that code like this was annoyingly hard to read, you can't really just read the code, you read the code, then you notice that the values are fetched from the database and now you have to look through the database schema all the time to understand it. When all you could do is just look at the class definition and knowing that there won't be any undocumented magic keys there.

So my question is how do you guys document code without getters and setters?

Comment: You seem to mixing up things here.  The recommendation not to use getters and setters in Python if not needed means that you shouldn't wrap plain instance attributes in getters and setters – it's not necessary in Python, since you can resort to properties to keep backwards compatibility if you decide to change the instance layout.

Comment: So you are saying `getName()` is self-documenting, but `instance.name` containing the name isn't?

Comment: Sure when you see it, but if you don't see the values from class definitions? Just by looking at the code can you make the assumption that it's always there, it's not some magic key/property that was just added for this part of the program?

Comment: If the code is adding new attributes to the class dynamically and these are part of the interface to that class, that is bad programming.

Comment: @Guu The Python naming convention is to name anything that is purely an implementation detail with a preceding underscore. E.g: `something._weight`.

Comment: The more I think this the more I feel like I should just tell clients to stop mapping database schema directly in to representation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there shouldn't be any undocumented attributes in a class. PHP and other languages allow you to just stick attributes on a class from anywhere, whether they've been defined in the class or not. I think that's bad practice for the reasons you describe and more:

It's hard to read.

It makes it harder for other programmers (including your future self) to understand what's going on.

It prevents auto-complete functionality in IDEs from working.

It often makes the domain layer too dependent on the persistence layer.

Whether you use getters and setters to access the defined attributes of a class is a little more fungible to me. I like things to be consistent, so if I have a class that has a getChildren() method to lazy load some array of objects, then I don't make the $children attribute public, and I tend to make other attributes private as well. I think that's a little more a matter of taste, but I find it annoying to access some attributes in a class directly ($object->name;) and others by getters/setters.

Comment: I'll accept this. The documentation should be made so that you can just make a quick look at the IDE and it should be obvious from there.